# Почему методы доступа {get;set;} с маленькой буквы

Tags: c#, setter, getter

Подскажите новичку принципы написания методов. В языке они пишуться по традиции с большой буквы, но методы доступа пишутся с маленькой. Речь идет о c#. Какой мотив такого исключения для этих методов ?

Comment: Это ключевые слова, у нас все ключевые слова пишутся маленькими буквами

Comment: Строго говоря, стиль написания кода устанавливается командой (вы можете установить в своей команде хоть из одного себя свой стиль) и писать хоть в camelCase, хоть в snake_case и уже третье дело, что это будет неудобно читать сторонней команде. Но с ключевыми словами у вас нет никакого выбора, как разработчики языка решили обозвать ключевые слова, так вы их и будете писать. Ну и следует отличать ключевые слова и *идентификаторы*, для которых как раз и могут быть соглашения

Comment: Названия свойствам вы даете сами. А get и set - это не названия, это _аксессоры_ (accessor).

Comment: Кстати, если хотите переопределять в языке ключевые слова и создавать новые, то просто возьмите другой язык программирования, позволяющий такую фичу.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще как писать название методов это ваша прихоть. Но ключевые слова (причём все) в языке C# пишутся строчными буквами. И точного ответа вам никто не даст, так как так решил создатель языка. Я не думаю то что пару слов в языке пишутся всегда строчными буквами, это ведь не влияет на вашу работоспособность, не так ли?

Comment: вроде не прихоть, а стиль написания методов с большой буквы, но ответ с ключевыми словами с одной стороны проясняет ситуацию, а с другой они все же выполняют роль методов.

Comment: @4uva не ну get и set в первую очередь являются ключевыми словами, а потом уже функционируют как методы доступа для переменных

Comment: Ваш ответ - как бы само собой разумеется. Но конкретно для таких вопросов, нужно либо не отвечать, либо отвечать с ссылками на стандарты, ECMA или хотя бы MSDN. Иначе простым вопросом "а почему всётаки так, а не так" вы попадаете в тупик.

Comment: Вопрос в ответе, кстати мне анекдот напоминает *- вы всегда отвечаете вопросом на вопрос? - а что?*:))))

Comment: @4uva: потому что `get` и `set` - не названия методов.